# Using django select_related with an additional filter

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I'm trying to find an optimal way to execute a query, but got myself confused with the prefetch_related and select_related use cases.

I have a 3 table foreign key relationship: A -> has 1-many B h-> as 1-many C.

```
class A(models.model):
   ...

class B(models.model):
   a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.model):
   b = models.ForeignKey(B)
   data = models.TextField(max_length=50)
```

I'm trying to get a list of all C.data for all instances of A that match a criteria (an instance of A and all its children), so I have something like this:

```
qs1 = A.objects.all().filter(Q(id=12345)|Q(parent_id=12345))
qs2 = C.objects.select_related('B__A').filter(B__A__in=qs1)
```

But I'm wary of the ([Prefetch docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) stating that:

> any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query
>   will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh
>   database query

I don't know if that applies here (because I'm using select_related), but reading it makes it seem as if anything gained from doing select_related is lost as soon as I do the filter.

Is my two-part query as optimal as it can be? I don't think I need prefetch as far as I'm aware, although I noticed I can swap out select_related with prefetch_related and get the same result.

Comment: You can inspect the actual sql using a queryset's `query` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is driven by a misconception. `select_related` (and `prefetch_related`) are an *optimisation*, specifically for returning values in related models along with the original query. They are *never* required.

What's more, neither has any impact at all on `filter`. Django will automatically do the relevant joins and subqueries in order to make your query, whether or not you use `select_related`.

Comment: With what you said in mind, it appears all I needed was  C.objects.filter(b__a__in=qs1) so yes, it it looks like I've well and truly misinterpreted the docs.